# ui-grid Filtering is not working with jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular and I am trying ui-grid. In my code, when I am clicking the filter button, I am not getting data and I am not getting any error either.  Can anyone please hep me?? This is my code:

HTML code:

```html
<input type="button" value="Filter" 
ng-model="filterValue" class="btn  btn-primary"                    
ng-click="applySearchFilter()" />
```

JavaScript code:

```js
 $scope.applySearchFilter = function () {         
        assignService.getResult($scope.RequestPrefix, $scope.RequestYear, $scope.RequestNumber, $scope.AssignedToStaff).then(function (assignResult) {
            $scope.assign = assignResult.data;          
            if ($scope.AssignedToStaff == "-1") {            
                $scope.assign = $.grep($scope.assign, function (element, index) {

                return element.AssignStaffId == 0;

               });
            }
        });
    };
```

```js
$scope.applySearchFilter = function () {
        alert("entering");      // init();
        assignService.getResult($scope.RequestPrefix, $scope.RequestYear, $scope.RequestNumber, $scope.AssignedToStaff).then(function (assignResult) {
            $scope.assign = assignResult.data;
            alert("Result");
            if ($scope.AssignedToStaff == "-1") {
                alert("if condition");
                $scope.assign = $.grep($scope.assign, function (element, index) {
                    alert("staff Data:::" + $scope.assign);
                return element.AssignStaffId == 0;

               });
            }
        });
    };
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="button" value="Filter" ng-model="filterValue" class="btn  btn-primary"
                   ng-click="applySearchFilter()" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure `assignService.getResult` promise really resolved, try to add a reject callback, to check whether the promise is resolved or not.

If the promise is resolved and you get the data from remote method, then you should check if ui-grid has updated its data in successful callback, I suppose you use `$scope.assign = assignResult.data;` to update ui-grid data, it looks no problem, but make sure in your ui-grid options, the data property should assigned a scope object name string, not a scope object:

```
$scope.uiGridOption = {
    data: 'assign',
    ...other options...
}

$scope.$scope.applySearchFilter = function () {
    assignService.getResult($scope.RequestPrefix, $scope.RequestYear, $scope.RequestNumber, $scope.AssignedToStaff).then(function (assignResult) {
        $scope.assign = assignResult.data;
        alert("Result");
        if ($scope.AssignedToStaff == "-1") {
            alert("if condition");
            $scope.assign = $.grep($scope.assign, function (element, index) {
                alert("staff Data:::" + $scope.assign);
            return element.AssignStaffId == 0;

           });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Ya in my ui-grid I have like that only.  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
        data: 'assign',
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true }  I am getting data in ui-grid by using $scope.assign = assignResult.data; but when I am selecting value from dropdown and then clicking filter button at that time the data is not coming..When I used this same code for nggrid it is working fine..Do I need to change anything in uigrid

Comment: Ya in my ui-grid I have like that only.  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
        data: 'assign',
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true }  I am getting data in ui-grid by using $scope.assign = assignResult.data; but when I am selecting value from dropdown and then clicking filter button at that time the data is not coming..When I used this same code for nggrid it is working fine..Do I need to change anything in uigrid